# time format yyyyMMddHHmmss in Hibernate 3.0

Tags: hibernate

I need time in "yyyyMMddHHmmss" format for Hibernate 3.0.

```
 <property name="delayTime" column="DELAYTIME" type=""/>
```

what i need to specify type to reflect time in above format?

Comment: What do you want actually ? Do you want the `delayTime` property of  the java entity is in the string format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` , and it maps to a DATE column which is called `DELAYTIME` in the DB??

Comment: Yes, DB column DELAYTIME is in date format. java entity is in string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [org.hibernate.usertype.UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html)

Create a class that implements that interface then:

1. in the method nullSafeGet convert the date object from the database into a string, for example using SimpleDateFormat
2. in the method nullSafeSet do the reverse.  Convert your string into a date object before saving into the database.

---

Actually the above answer seems like overkill.  Why not just keep the date as a java.util.Date in the hibernate object.  Then you can have methods like:

```
private Date date;
public String getDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(YOUR_FORMAT);
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
}
public void setDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(YOUR_FORMAT);
    this.date = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
}
```

Hibernate can use the private date.  The rest of your code can use the String.

Comment: org.hibernate.usertype.UserType shows hibernate3.5 , will it work for 3.0 version?

Comment: @kasim Check your documentation for 3.0, but yes usertypes should work there.

Comment: "Hibernate can use the private date. The rest of your code can use the String." ie no need of specifying date format type in hbm.xml file? if I don't specify it will consider as default format isn't it?

Comment: @kasim Your hibernate configuration (property name="delayTime") needs to tell hibernate to get the data from the java.util.Date object. This can either be from a method or from the property directly.  The rest of your code base can use a different methods from hibernate that use SimpleDateFormat.